# BigQuery: Insert into temporary table

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the closest approximation in BigQuery to this MS-SQL (T-SQL) syntax? I am running the browser version of Google's BigQuery.

```
select * 
into #myNewTempTable
from myTable
```

In MS-SQL this will create a temporary table without having to specify the table structure. (I don't particularly care about how long the table persists.) Thank you!

**Hint**: This will create a table without having to specify the table structure, but it's not a temporary table.

```
create table `datascience-291801.temp.premier_cohort_heart` as
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE myNewTempTable AS 
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.myTable`
```